# Solving a general Bernoulli diferential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So this is the equation.
$a,b,N_0 \in \mathbb{R}, ab>0$
$$N'(x)= aN(x)-bN(x)^2, (x\in[0,\infty)), N(0) = N_0$$

First things first $\color{red}I $  need to transform this,

If we let $N = w^{1/2}$, then after some calculation, (I don't think this part is the issue...)

$$w' +aw = b, w(0) = N_0^2$$

This has general solution;

$$w(x) = e^{ax}(N_0^2+\frac{b}{a}(1-e^{-ax}))$$

so

$$N(x) = \sqrt{e^{ax}(N_0^2+\frac{b}{a}(1-e^{-ax}))}$$

Now I need to find the $\color{red}{\text{maximally extended solutions}}$.

for the solution to be defined, it is fair to say that the statement in the bracket needs to be positive

$$e^{ax} > \frac{b/a}{N_0^2 + b/a}$$, I suppose this is a good time to split into cases.

$a >0$
If this is so then there could be an interval $K$ where $e^{ax} \leq \frac{b/a}{N_0^2 + b/a}$

So if a >0 then the solution is defined on $(\frac{1}{a}\ln \frac{b/a}{N_0^2 + b/a},\infty)$ but in this case my initial condition is not in the domain I just stated?

Now in the case that $a < 0$ we can find an interval $(k,\infty)$ where the solution is not defined. since $e^{ax}$ is decreasing.

I am not doing all that well with these ODE's. I am sure I am overlooking the relationship between $N_0$ and, a,b as well.

EDIT:

I think the solution is defined for all $x \in [0, \infty)$ if $a >0$, this is because $\frac{b/a}{N_0^2 + b/a} <1$

In the case $a < 0$ we have that the solution is defined on $x \in [0, \frac{1}{a}\ln \frac{b/a}{N_0^2 + b/a})$

Comment: Why not solving it as a separable ODE ?. The very simple integration leads to $y=\frac{a}{b+c\:e^{-ax}}$

Comment: Why $N=w^{1/2}$?

Comment: Is there not a mistake in $\omega ' +a\omega = b$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$N'(x)=aN(x)+bN(x)^2$$

The change of variable $\quad N=\omega^{1/2}\quad $ is strange since it leads to an ODE more complicated than the original one.

$N'=\frac{\omega'}{2\:\omega^{1/2}}$

$$\frac{\omega'}{2\:\omega^{1/2}} = a\:\omega^{1/2}+b\:\omega$$

$$\omega'= 2a\:\omega +b\: \omega^{3/2}$$

The transformed ODE is non-linear. So, what is the interest ?

Nevertheless, this is a separable ODE which solution is : 
$$\omega=\frac{4a^2}{\left(b+c\:e^{-ax}\right)^2}$$

$$N(x)=\frac{2a}{b+c\:e^{-ax}}$$

This is exactly the same result than if we directly solve $N'=aN+bN^2$ which is separable.

The condition $\quad N(0)=N_0\quad$ or $\quad\omega(0)=N_0^2\quad$ gives $\quad c=\frac{2a}{N_0}-b$

$$\omega=\frac{4a^2}{\left(b+(\frac{2a}{N_0}-b)\:e^{-ax}\right)^2}$$

$$N(x)=\frac{2a}{b+(\frac{2a}{N_0}-b)\:e^{-ax}}$$

If $2a>bN_0$ there is no restriction of the domaine from $x=0\to\infty$ while $N=N_0\to\frac{2a}{b}$

If $2a=bN_0$ the domain is from $x=0\to\infty$ and  $N(x)=N_0$

If $2a<bN_0$ the domaine is restricted to $0\leq x < x_m\quad$ where $\quad x_m=\frac{1}{a}\ln\left(1-\frac{2a}{bN_0} \right)\quad$ while $\quad N$ increasses from $N_0$ to blow-up.